# How to hide different rows based on two seperate drop down boxes?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am sure there is an easy fix to this, but I cannot figure out why the first if statement is working and the second one is not. The 1st statement to hide 57:68 works but the second statement of hiding 70:78 does not work. VBA is not giving me an error. Can someone help me fix this? Thank you!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub

ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "NO" Then
    Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "YES" Then
    Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

If Intersect(Target, Range("B5")) Is Nothing Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub

ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "NO" Then
    Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "YES" Then
    Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the very first "IF" statement of your code? I presume the dropboxes are on B4 and B5?

Comment: Yes B4 and B5 are the drop boxes. I guess I am not sure of what I was trying to achieve except to reference the cell for the if statement. I think I have over complicated it. I have two questions and the user selects Yes or No and if it is YES for either one - nothing is hidden. If it is NO for either one - those specific cells gets hidden. The first one in cell B4 is working - nothing changes in B5 when Yes or No are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B4")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target = "No" Then Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            If Target = "Yes" Then Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5")) Is Nothing And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target = "NO" Then Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            If Target = "YES" Then Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are checking other conditions, your code can be reduced to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("B4").Value = "NO" Then
    Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf Range("B4").Value = "YES" Then
    Rows("57:68").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

If Range("B5").Value = "NO" Then
    Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = True

ElseIf Range("B5").Value = "YES" Then
    Rows("70:78").EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

End Sub
```